# PHP function's parameter is unclear

Tags: php

```
function test($param=null) {
    if ($param===null)
      .....
}
```

Since $param is set to null at function header, why even bother test if $param===null? If there a case $param wouldn't be null?

Comment: parameters sometimes passed with function call. Go figure

Answer (score 2):

That is an optional/[default argument](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.default).

If you call that function, then you can call it one of two ways:

```
test($value);
```

or

```
test();
```

In the first case, `$param` holds the value of `$value`. In the second case, `$param` is always `null`.

Answer (score 1):

> Since $param is set to null at function header, why even bother test
>   if $param===null? if there a case $param wouldn't be null?

That is *optional* argument because you define default value of `null` to it.

As for why bother checking it, *you want to make sure a parameter was indeed specified which is NOT `null`.*

Let's assume you wanted to `echo` it:

```
function test($param=null) {
  echo $param;
}
```

When you call the function, nothing would happen and you don't want to do that, right. For that reason, you want to make sure that value of argument is NOT null so that you could manipulate it however you like.

**Tests:**

```
function test($param=null) {
  echo $param;
}

test(); // no output
test('hello there'); // output: hello there
```

Answer (score 1):

`$param` will only be null if no value is passed to the function. This is an example of [optional parameters](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php).

You could call the function by passing a value

```
test(10); //$param inside the method will be 10;
test();   //$param will be null
```

Answer (score 0):

$param=null is a default variable only, overwritten when the function is called with a variable.

if you call the function using

```
 $helloworld = test('notnull');
```

then $param will equal 'notnull' in the function.

Answer (score 0):

A case $param wouldn't be null:

```
test("ok");
```

In this case, $param = "ok".